# Conditional Formatting in a line chart in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I want to change color of the gray line in below chart (format - red to decrease and green to increase) every month. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: you mean to make the same line red and green? I don't think you can do that. See here for how to dynamicaly change the color of trend line, http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-format-trend-line-color-in-excel-dynamically/

Answer (score 2):

I used the following table in this workaround (starting from A1), filled B2:C10 with zeroes and created a line chart with values from cell range B2:C10:

[image]

Please note that I used the following formula for "Up" column and "Down" column, respectively:

```
=IF(COUNT($A1)>0, IF(OR($A2<$A3, $A2>$A1), $A2, "delete"), IF($A2<$A3, $A2, "delete"))

=IF(COUNT($A1)>0, IF(OR($A2>$A3, $A2<$A1), $A2, "delete"), IF($A2>$A3, $A2, "delete"))
```

What the formula does is check first if the value above the current checked cell is a number. If it is a number, for "Up" column formula, it checks the current checked cell's value if it is greater than the value above it or less than the value below and display that value if true or `delete` if not. For "Down" column, it's just the opposite value checking. Just tweak the formula to adapt if there's no change in the value.

**Steps**

1. Replace the values in B2 and C2 by pasting the formula above in their respective columns.

[image]

2. Select cells B2 and C2 and paste them to the rest of the rows (B3:C10). Select cell range B2:C10, copy and paste as value. There should be no formula left in cell range B2:10.

[image]

3. Using cell range B2:C10, find and replace `delete` with blanks.

[image]

So it becomes like this:

[image]

4. Replace the line colors with the ones you want to use.